# How to update in mysql or php script a column based on dependents?

Tags: mysql

```
countries               
id  co_code country
1   10      Japan
2   11      China
3   12      Korea

cities          
id  co_code city
1   11      Shanghai
2   12      Seoul
3   10      Osaka
4   11      Beijing
5   10      Tokyo
```

I need to update the cities table as shown below. Do i need to develop a php script or it can be done in sql query?

```
cities                  
id  country_id  city
1   2          Shanghai
2   3          Seoul
3   1          Osaka
4   2          Beijing
5   1          Tokyo
```

this does'nt work for me.

```
INSERT INTO newcities (id, country_id, city)
SELECT
  co_code, city
FROM
  cities
WHERE
  id = co_code
```

the dependency of cities must based on countries id. Any help would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you show an `INSERT` but in the text you speak about updating the table? Do you want to make a new table or alter and update the old one?

Comment: update or creating new table just fine. no problem if copy or create new table. just as the id will be updated or created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. You can create a new table (call it `newcities`) from the old `cities` table, and then `DROP` the `cities` table and rename `newcities` to `cities`:

```
CREATE TABLE newcities AS
SELECT ci.id, co.id AS country_id, ci.city
FROM cities ci
JOIN countries co ON co.co_code = ci.co_code;

DROP TABLE cities;
ALTER TABLE newcities RENAME cities
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xawZ4WbaWeQFxSfmKtqe7F/0)

Or you can update the table in situ:

```
ALTER TABLE cities CHANGE co_code country_id INT;

UPDATE cities ci
JOIN countries co ON co.co_code = ci.country_id
SET ci.country_id = co.id
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xawZ4WbaWeQFxSfmKtqe7F/1)

Comment: your answer is very usefull. both ways you have suggested works fine... thanks a lot. this saves much of my time browsing different samples on the web.

Comment: @JohnArzaga why did you decide to no longer accept this answer? The one you have accepted is not even correct.

Comment: I just thought I could accept more than 1 answer. :))

Comment: @JohnArzaga Unfortunately no... I agree sometimes it would be good. But you can upvote as many as you like...

Comment: Yeah, how i wish i could appreciate everyone that contributes and share what they know...

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE C1
SET C1.CO_CODE = C2.CO-CODE
FROM CITY C1
INNER JOIN CITY2 C2
ON C1.ID = C2.ID
```

This will update the existing city table to the new city table based off of the id in the city table.  If you are looking to reference table 1 and get the values from there instead you can follow a similar query but join to the countries table.

Comment: sticky bit and Matt D thanks a lot. that also works ok. tried it done.